# PostgreSQL compare datetime with timestamp

Tags: php, postgresql

I have datetime field in my postgreSQL table, and I want to select fields, comparing with timestamp variables, example: `(date_time >= ".$from_date." AND date_time <= ".$to_date)` where `$from_date` and `$to_date` contains timestamp. I tried `date("Y-m-d h:m:i",$from_date)` but I got **syntax error at or near "12". The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cars_pay_history" "t" WHERE date_time >= 2017-12-03 12:12:00** .

Comment: Are you selecting from two tables?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo no, from one table

Comment: `$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars_pay_history AS t WHERE date_time >= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$from_date)."' AND date_time <= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$to_date)."'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote and typecast your embedded dates:

```
$sql = "
[...]
where
    date_time between '" . date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $from_date) . "'::timestamp and '" . date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $to_date) . "'::timestamp
"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query  = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars_pay_history AS t ";
$query .= "WHERE date_time >= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$from_date)."' ";
$query .= "AND date_time < '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$to_date)."'";
```

Care with the format specified in the `date` function since:

```
h:m:i =
    h => 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros (it should be 24-hour format instead, unless you use A -AM/PM- to distinguish)
    m => numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros (it should be minutes instead)
    i => minutes with leading zeros (it should be seconds instead)
```

You should use `H:i:s` instead.